Entering USA for the first time through Canadian borders
My mother (Jordanian Passport) has a visit visa to the USA
she also has a Canadian visit Visa
The plan is to fly directly to Canada through Europe,
Stay in Canada for 2 weeks, then drive to Detroit through Windsor-Detroit borders by bus.
Will there by any restrictions entering USA for the first time through land borders?
As we will be taking the bus, will it take long time to grant allow her to enter (as I doubt bus will be waiting for hours till the process is done << in case the process takes hours >>)

Related question with possibly useful information https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24883/how-much-extra-time-should-i-reserve-to-enter-the-us-from-canada-with-the-windso?rq=1

Jordan is not part of the US Visa Waiver Program, so before reaching the US border your mother first needs to have a US visa which would be appropriate for the visit (B1/B2, I imagine). She would probably need to apply for it in Jordan (although I know some non-residents getting visas in Canada, it is almost always people working in the US already).
Once the visa is in the passport, she doesn't need anything else. However, the border checks may take time. There's nothing special for the "first" visit - the requirements are always the same.
I have never used buses to cross the US border, but I had in other places, and at least in one case the bus almost left without me because the checks took too long. While probably not the likeliest of scenarios, suggest to have contingency plans for such an event.

The first paragraph is somewhat superfluous in light of the first sentence of the question.  More importantly, I get the sense that someone with a passport from a country seen as "Muslim" is far more likely to be held up for a significant time at the border.  The possibility of missing the bus may not be so unlikely in this case.
